# Errors in logging out of Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, exception

I have integrated the Facebook in my application which works well while logging in,  but when I try to logout I get many errors which I couldn't resolve. There were similar questions asked in stack overflow ([Facebook Log Out error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339393/facebook-log-out-error-in-android), [Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009816/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)), but solution for that posts didn't workout for me.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
    ListView LVdrawer;
    ImageView toplogo;
    View rL;
    Facebook fb;
    Handler handler;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        rL = findViewById(R.id.toplogoaction);
        handler=new Handler();
            drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        LVdrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        LVdrawer.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, 0));
        fb=new Facebook(getString(R.string.APP_ID));
            get();
        LVdrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                                TextView ttt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
                String s = (String) ttt.getText();
                drawerlayout.closeDrawers();

                switch (s) {
                case "Now":
                    if(fb.isSessionValid()){

                        Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loggedout",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            }
                        };

                            new Thread(runnable).start();
                                }
                    break;

                }
            }
        });
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void get() {
        SharedPreferences Logininfo = getSharedPreferences("accesstoken", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (Logininfo.getString("access_token", null) != null) {
            fb.setAccessToken(Logininfo.getString("access_token", null));
            if (Logininfo.getLong("access_expires", 0) != 0)
                fb.setAccessExpires(Logininfo.getLong("access_expires", 0));
        }

    }


 }
```

Logcat:

```
09-15 16:16:40.138: D/Facebook-Util(9594): GET URL: https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?access_token=CAAMKZCWmSwAABAC5ZB3hbry1FLMNdsKssmaS1OpiUxCK9ZAnn3OCKclKNAJ0DTVaf5M6d9QREeTZAsJWKNFWrt65vH5STZBeW0dL9A1l59xSuuqh1RmZALDgFLIxZBiEsXTGE4bR1pkEFQZBA8DfK81ZAjbe1V34JBddgrr0UxKOYkNDqEJc1WWZB8H9TZCbMZCpZCEk6ESusNzxBldzpVKHZBnNNr&format=json&method=auth.expireSession
09-15 16:16:40.211: D/AndroidRuntime(9594): Shutting down VM
09-15 16:16:40.211: W/dalvikvm(9594): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ecd40)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594): Process: com.example.apeonomy, PID: 9594
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:224)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:804)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:707)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:649)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logout(Facebook.java:642)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.digiapes.apeonomy.Main$1$1$1.run(Main.java:92)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-15 16:16:40.217: E/AndroidRuntime(9594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 16:16:46.330: I/Process(9594): Sending signal. PID: 9594 SIG: 9
```

Updated(Logcat) after using AsyncTask:

```
09-15 16:42:11.022: D/Facebook-Util(14618): GET URL: https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?access_token=CAAMKZCWmSwAABAC5ZB3hbry1FLMNdsKssmaS1OpiUxCK9ZAnn3OCKclKNAJ0DTVaf5M6d9QREeTZAsJWKNFWrt65vH5STZBeW0dL9A1l59xSuuqh1RmZALDgFLIxZBiEsXTGE4bR1pkEFQZBA8DfK81ZAjbe1V34JBddgrr0UxKOYkNDqEJc1WWZB8H9TZCbMZCpZCEk6ESusNzxBldzpVKHZBnNNr&format=json&method=auth.expireSession
09-15 16:42:12.626: W/dalvikvm(14618): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ecd40)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): Process: com.example.apeonomy, PID: 14618
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:90)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:324)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:348)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.facebook.Session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(Session.java:801)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:665)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logout(Facebook.java:642)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.digiapes.apeonomy.Main$myAsy.doInBackground(Main.java:164)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at com.digiapes.apeonomy.Main$myAsy.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-15 16:42:12.630: E/AndroidRuntime(14618):    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Create This Class in your FacebookSDK in com.facebook package

```
package com.facebook;

import android.content.Context;

public class Door {
  public static void initializeStaticContext(Context context) {
    Session.initializeStaticContext(context);
  }
}
```

call `Door.initializeStaticContext(this.getApplicationContext());` before calling logout